# How to convert a List of String bits (["0","0","1","0"] etc) into an int in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, binary, byte

My input is List for example

```
["0","0","0","0","0","1","0","1"]
```

and I'm looking to convert into integer for my output to be the `int` of  `5`

Here is my code i could able to convert list into string by using `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for(String str : list)  {
 builder.append(str);
 }

builder.toString()   //00000101
```

Comment: Tried anything so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Integer.parseInt()` with `radix` and `String.join` to convert `List` into `String`

```
Integer.parseInt(String.join("",list),2);
```

> Parses the string argument as a signed integer in the radix specified by the second argument

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach without the overhead of String manipulation.

```java
      String[] bits = { "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1"
      };
      int val = 0;
      for (String b : bits) {
         val <<= 1;
         val |= b.charAt(0) - '0';
      }
      System.out.println(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

convert string result to integer using `Integer.parseInt("string",2)`

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String str : list)  {
 builder.append(str);
 }

builder.toString() ;  //00000101
int output = Integer.parseInt(builder.toString(),2); // 5
```